Can i get rid of the http:// from the textbox when adding a quick link/top header link in SharePoint Online
Can i get rid of the http:// from the textbox when adding a quick link/top header link?
I need to add a link of an application that doesn't have or start with http://
Is this possible to remove or change this?

Thanks in Advance

This is by design, you have to enter an URL with http or https.

This is the expected behavior in SharePoint Online. This issue occurs
because the file:// protocol isn't supported for local files in the
Promoted Links list. The http:// and https:// protocols are supported
in the Promoted Links list in SharePoint Online.

Source: "Invalid URL" error when you click a SharePoint Online Promoted Link which uses the file:// protocol
